# Probability that an observation is from a known population

Tags: probability

This seems like it should be an easy question, at least the first part, but I can't think of the right way to do it or the search terms needed to google it.

Given a normal random variable $X$ with known distribution, what is the probability that an observation $r$ came from $X$? Is this even a well-posed question, or do I need to define some priors?

My end goal is, given a large set of random variables, $X_1 \dots X_n$, I want a **quick** way of assigning probabilities that a given measurement is from each random variable. Assuming I can reasonably define a closeness metric, $\rho_i$, for the measurement to each $X_i$ I can do
$$
\begin{align}
P(r \text{ is from} X_i) &= \frac{\rho_i}{\sum_{k=1}^n \rho_k}
\end{align}
$$

Bonus:
What if the observation $r$ includes measurement noise (normally distributed)?

Double bonus:
How do I extend this to bivariate normal distributions?

Comment: I know you can do this for a sample, but just one observation doesn't seem quite enough, imo, to see if the distribution matches (or in other words if it comes from a population with a given distribution).

Comment: That question is actually slightly different conceptually in that it's asking if two distributions are the same, but I'm just trying to check if a point is from a known distribution.

Comment: Yes yes, I might have expressed myself badly. What I was trying to say was that (and someone correct me if I'm wrong) I think one point is just not enough to check if it comes from a given distribution. It could as well be from any other distribution because one point does not convey enough information about the population it might be from. I'm not entirely sure about his though ;)

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I was a little bit unsure of that myself, which is why I asked if it was even a well-posed question.

If that's the case, then, when requiring that it comes from 1 of the distributions, $X_1 \dots X_n$, it should make the problem well-posed, shouldn't it?

Comment: So the new problem:  An observation r comes from one of the random variables $X_1....X_n$, what is the probability that it comes from $X_i$?

Comment: Yes that's something you can do because you now have a finite set of possible prior distribution.
@Sadar I guess he did mean exactly this

Comment: @Dolma No, you can't. For a continuous random variable $P(X=x)=0$ and this is true for all of them. There is no information in a single data point.

Comment: @Sadar Yes, that is the problem scenario.

DaleM So what further information would be needed to make this a properly formed problem? I have a single measurement with measurement noise (bonus 1) so I'm not exactly trying to find P(X=x). Other than that the problem is simply to find the probably that a measurement comes from a known distribution.

Comment: @DaleM: I forgot that property, of course you're right ! :)

Comment: Thinking about it some more, it likes like $P(X=x)=0$ is a red herring here. Using $r \in X_i$ to indicate that $r$ comes from population $X_i$, by the total probability law we have
$$
\begin{align}
P(r) = P(r | r \in X_1) + P(r | r \in X_2) + ... + P(r | r \in X_n)
\end{align}
$$
And since I have already observed $r$ I know $P(r)=1$ so $P(r | r \in X_i)$ has to be nonzero for some $X_i$.

Comment: That is like saying my poker hand has 4 aces therefore P(4 aces)=1. You cannot establish the probabilities applying before the event from a single sample.

Comment: Ah, yes, my example is flawed. I still think $P(X=r)=0$ is going the wrong direction though. That is saying, given a continuous distribution $X$, what is the probability of $r$? Since there are infinitely many observations possible the probability of a single measurement goes to zero. In my case, I'm starting with observation $r$ and and want to know the probability of $X_i$, of which there are finite many possibilities.

Using your card example: given that I have 4 aces and $n$ decks where the number of aces is a random variable, what is the probability that it came from deck $X_i$?

Comment: ooh, I think that got me down the right path.
$$
\begin{align}
p(X_i | r) &= \frac{p(r | X_i) p(X_i)}{p(r)}
\\
&= \frac{p(r | X_i) p(X_i)}{\sum_{k=1}^n p(r | X_k) p(X_k)}
\end{align}
$$

So I just need to defined $p(X_i)$ which, lacking any other information, I can treat as a uniform distribution.

Comment: $X_i$ is a random value, so taking the probability of this does not make sense. You can only take probabilities of events.

Comment: It's a bit of an abuse of notation, but here the 'event' is observation $r$ coming from $X_i$. $p(X_i)$ is simply the probability of the random variable $X_i$ existing.

Comment: All comments were not so helpful i can imagine, but I will give a naive answer to be more constructive

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number of random variables with known distribution and you know that a value $r$ is realised by exactly one variable. Then one can define the distribution of $Y$ ($Y=i$ if $r$ from $X_i$) as being:

$$P(Y=i)= \frac{f_i(r)}{\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(r)}$$

where $f_i(x)$ is the density function of $X_i$.

Intuitively working with densities makes sense, because if the $X_i$ are continuous and $f_i(r)> f_j(r)$ for a $i$ and $j$ then there is a $\delta$ such that $P(X_i \in (r-\delta,r+\delta)) > P(X_j \in (r-\delta,r+\delta))$. But densities are not probabilities, so caution is advised.

For the bonus: If you include noise which is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$, one can take $(r-\epsilon,r+\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ chosen so you have coverage with which you feel comfortable. Now you can use normal probabilities and state:

$$P(Y=i) =\frac{P(X_i \in (r-\epsilon,r+\epsilon))}{\sum_{k=1}^n P(X_ \in (r-\epsilon,r+\epsilon))}$$