# probability of belonging to a class if distribution of classes are known

Tags: probability, density-function

Consider a population of samples that depend on a variable $X$ and are distributed between one of 2 classes (e.g. Green and Red like this).

[image]

The probability density functions $p_G(x)$ and $p_R(x)$ for each of the 2 classes are known.

Given a value for $X=x$, what is the probability $P(G|X=x)$ or $P(R|X=x)$ that a sample belongs to one or the other class ?

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364218/probability-that-an-observation-is-from-a-known-population), I suspect that: $$P(G|X=x) = \frac{p_G(x)}{p_G(x)+p_R(x)}$$
But how can it be proved formally ?

Comment: If initially before observing $x$ you had  Red and Green being equally likely, then your result is an application of [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).  Incidentally it is usual to write $X=x$ where $X$ is the random variable and $x$ the observed value, making your formula $\mathbb P(G\mid X=x) = \dfrac{p_G(x)}{p_G(x)+p_R(x)}$

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the notation, and your comment about Baye's theorem is indeed the answer.

Comment: As another minor comment, [Thomas Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bayes) had Ss at the ends of his names